# time-animation of a latitude/longitude observations - best approach?

Tags: python, animation, mesh, scripting

I'm trying to develop a skill to display space-time data in 3D Blender space.  In general, the X and Y dimensions would be longitude and latitude, and the Z dimension would be any one of dozens of numeric float variables.  All of the data would typically display on a map, with observations at irregular (not evenly gridded) positions to create a "sheet" (like an elevation map) of hills and valleys.  One sheet would be a snapshot of a point in time, and I would have many (hundreds) of sheets of sequential snapshots in time that I would like to display as animation.

At the moment, for technique development, I'm working with daily high temperatures at ~2500 US weather stations across 365 days.

I've been working on this pretty much full time for a couple of weeks, trying to do this with Blender Python scripting and csv files, with great progress, but in the last 2 days I've gotten stuck.  Rather than post my code, or a simplified version of it that anyone could run to show where I am stuck, I'm rethinking that maybe I'm thinking about this animation problem completely incorrectly, so I'm asking anyone here for reactions and comments.

My python/Blender code right now, trying to animate thru 365 days in a year, is creating 365 sheets or maps, and they are all stacking up in a "thick" pile (like a sandwich of data).  I have 365 keyframes created, but I cant see any movement because the top and bottom surfaces of the sandwich are enclosing any movement that might be going on in the stack of (Jan 1 to Dec 31) daily sheets.  FYI, I used Delaunay triangulation elsewhere in Python to create face triangles that connect the discrete points (irregular spatially though fixed and complete across time, not sparse).

So my question - how to structure this animation problem in a Blender script - is an either/or choice: 1) should I try to fix my 365 keyframed sheet approach, or 2) should I restructure the approach completely....with ONE sheet / surface of connected triangles "deforming" in time as the z-values of the vertices evolve?

If my original/current approach 1 is correct, I can either share the code of the core, or simplify then share it as a 15 line program that is self-contained, but if approach 1 is obviously wrong, I can abandon it and start re-structuring now to approach 2.  Is it obvious what is the right approach?  I'm still too inexperienced with animation to know.

Thanks loads, and I apologize in advance if this is not understandable.  OK for you to say that if true.

Comment: At the moment this reads  akin to _"I have been working (paid?) on this for two weeks and have nothing to show.. Can I do better?  Please show me"_

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  It's unpaid.  Just me.  I finally found something insightful and high quality late last night which helps my understanding.  The person codes 3 level, nested loops for x, y, with object creation inside the middle loop, then in inner third loop, moves the object progressively, keyframing that object with each movement.  Not sure whether it is a best practice, or one of several ways, but it is disciplined and rigorous.  This was the insight I was seeking, whether you animate “scenes”, or each object within scenes.  Seems to be latter.  Comments or suggestions welcome.